# unknown member or unable to edit control of grid's column on page frame

Tags: visual-foxpro

I've one grid created on second page of page frame and linked to .PRG file for each time activate on different page. Under Activate events, each grid's column defined its own member class created under .PRG file.The problem is I couldn't able to access to each member control of grid's columns even I tried to change it but it will remain same class created under individual page's activate events.

I won't initialise the gird's column control base class on grid's init event because I need to set additive access to different .PRG file When access on different page. This problem of failed to access column member or control of grid won't be exists in form when I initalised grid's member control under grid's init events. BTW,i'm using vfp 6.

**My Code under Page item Activate Events**

```
set procedure to 
set procedure to cn_pro additive
for count = thisform.page_.pages(thisform.page_.activepage).grid_list.columncount to 1 step -1
   column_ = "column" + alltrim(str(count))
   thisform.page_.pages( thisform.page_.activepage ).grid_list.removeobject( "&column_")
next

with thisform.page_.pages(thisform.page_.activepage).grid_list
   .addobject("column1","column")
   .columns(1).visible  = .t.
   .columns(1).bound    = .t.
   .columns(1).width    = 75
   .columns(1).header1.alignment    = 2 
   .columns(1).header1.caption  = "Mod_Qty"
   .columns(1).removeobject("text1")
   .columns(1).addobject("btn_qty","btn_quan")
   .columns(1).currentcontrol   = "btn_qty"
   .columns(1).btn_qty.visible  = .t.
   .columns(1).btn_qty.caption  = "Mod Qty"
   .columns(1).sparse   = .f.
endwith

create cursor tmpcur(btn_qty logical null)
use in select('tmpcur')
use in dbf('tmpcur') in 0 again alias tmpcur_
use in tmpcur

thisform.page_.pages(thisform.page_.activepage).grid_list.recordsource  = ""
thisform.page_.pages(thisform.page_.activepage).grid_list.recordsource  = "tmpcur_"
thisform.page_.pages(thisform.page_.activepage).grid_list.refresh()

**My class code in cn_pro.PRG file(Same example 1 problem)**

define class frm as form
   procedure keypress
   LPARAMETERS nKeyCode, nShiftAltCtrl
      for each frm_ in _screen.forms
         if alltrim(frm_.name) == "MAIN"
            scan 
               with frm_.page_.pages( frm_.page_.activepage ).grid_list
                  **=>Example is here I've two record inside the grid, 
                  **=>I want to change the property of button or access on it.**
                  .column1.btn_qty.enabled = .f. 
                  **=>It will return Error message said "unknown member btn_qty" How to fix it?** 
               endwith
            endscan
         endif
      endfor
   endpro
enddefine

**My class code in cn_pro.PRG file(Same example 2 problem)**
define class frm as form
   procedure keypress
   LPARAMETERS nKeyCode, nShiftAltCtrl

      for each frm_ in _screen.forms
         if alltrim(frm_.name) == "MAIN"
            scan 
               with frm_.page_.pages(frm_.page_.activepage).grid_list
                  **=>Example is here I've two record inside the grid, 
                  **=>I want to change the property of button or access on it.**
                  .removeobject('column1') 
                  **=>Remove entire column1 contained with** commandbutton "btn_qty"
                  .createobject('column1','column')
                  .column1.bound = .t.
                  .column1.text1.visible = .t.
                  .column1.sparse = .f.
                  .refresh() 
                  **=> Previous CommandButton on column1 should be changed and
                  ** replace with text here but It won't change and still be 
                  ** same commandbutton.Why, How to fix it?**
               endwith
            endscan
         endif
      endfor
   endpro
enddefine
```

Hopefully anyone could solve my problem here.Thanks!

Comment: I would like to help you but can't figure out what you are trying to do.  Are you simply trying to assign different custom button objects to a grid?

Comment: I have done quite a bit with dynamically building grids, columns, custom headers, click handling, custom controls, etc.  I will keep an eye out, and if you are interested, I can mentor you on some techniques outside this forum as it would be too much to bloat this single question.  Let me know an email and I'll get back to you on it with more detail...

Comment: Why would you ever remove/add a column in each activate over and over? Simply do that once in grid.Init or in form.Init if it is has some dependency on init of other controls. You don't need to have it in base grid.init, but surely you could do that on instance grid.init.

Comment: Dear DRAPP, Thank you for your concern, you could drop me email address at koklim7@hotmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your approach will not work.  You don't need to remove columns, you need to add/remove objects to the column and then set the columns current control property to the control you want.

If you want a variety of different controls to display for the same column, then you set the dynamiccurrentcontrol property to an expression that will look at a value and then return the name of the column.control that you want to display dependent upon the logical comparison in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've ready found the solution, the reason why it unable detect button(control members fo grid) because it is created right after return focus to main form when you have grid created on page frame.

```
m.result = .t.
frm_.page_.pages(frm_.page_.activepage).btn_print.setfocus() =>to set it focus for later trigger btn_print's gotfocus 
=>event,which will be able to change property's of member control of grids.

this.release =>exit "frm" class

Coding for btn_print gotfocus
if m.result=.t.
m.result = .f.
with this.parent.gid_list
.columns(1).btn_qty.enabled = .f.
endwith 
endif
```

Struggle me for one day more until i could find out the reason and solution.